# Snapseed vs Lightroom PC output quality

Tags: lightroom, image-quality, mobile

All of them has some pluses and minuses.

My concern is, if I process the photo in Snapseed in to the final form with tools which Snapseed offer. Will the output quality be great as same as Lightroom PC output quality ?

I am not talking about lack of features, just purely about image quality

Thank you

Comment: What does "image quality" mean to you?

Comment: If I do the same adjustments in both applications and print the pictures, both will have same amount of details

Comment: Again...not really a fair statement. Each program has differing algorithms or ways of handling editing. While it might be possible to get the same print from each program...I'd doubt it would be done using the exact same settings. The point would be that each program offers you tools, and do those tools meet your needs?

Answer (score 1):

I've used both Snapseed and Lightroom for some time. I also made prints from images that were post-processed in Lightroom and processed in Snapseed. As I recall, I never noticed a visual "quality" drop by Snapseed. When I browse (digitally) my final images and show them to clients, no one can tell which ones were edited in Lightroom, VSCO (another mobile application), or Snapseed.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve used both programs and the end image quality when saving haven’t shown any difference. I’d just say with Lightroom you have more flexibility in choosing the exact quality you’d like to achieve when saving the image